# Object and subject in the sentence with to be verbs

Tags: subjects, objects

How can I determine the object and subject of sentences with to be verb?

For example, what are the object and subject of the below sentence?

> The impacts of new changes are insignificant

Comment: It should be "The impact of new changes **is** insignificant". The subject is "the impact of new changes". There is no object: "significant" is predicative complement of "be".

Comment: Thanks Billj, I edited

Comment: Do you understand my comment about subject and object?

Comment: Yes, it makes sense